# django - Mutual relations between models: How to create instances?

Tags: python, django, django-models

With a model like

```
class Restaurant:
    default_pizza = models.OneToOneField('Pizza', on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Pizza:
    served_in = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

how can I create a new restaurant object and a corresponding default_pizza object at the same time?
A restaurant can serve many pizzas, but only one will be the default pizza.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just an "empty" pizza set it as a default value:

```
class Restaurant:
    def pizza_default():
        return Pizza.objects.create()
    default_pizza = models.OneToOneField('Pizza', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=pizza_default)
```

And then: `Restaurant.objects.create()`

If you want to specify the default pizza object on creation pass it in as a parameter:

```
Restaurant.objects.create(default_pizza=<the default pizza>)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because when calling pizza_default, 'served_in' is not set resulting in a NOT NULL constraint failed / IntegrityError

Comment: You should be able to set the `served_in` on object creation too: So instead of `return Pizza.objects.create()` you do `return Pizza.objects.create(served_in=self)`.

Comment: This won't do either. The problem is, that the database enforces the NOT NULL constraint for the OneToOneField & the ForeignKey field on a database level. What I'm looking for is a way to insert the two objects at the same time into the database.